# Slack channel doesn't work with MS Bot Framework

Tags: bots, botframework, slack-api

I have created many bots with MS Bot Framework and they worked correctly, following the instructions of the proper channel (in `https://dev.botframework.com/` -> Add another channel -> Add).

They all, including Slack, worked properly, but now app creation in Slack (`https://api.slack.com/applications/new`) is different to the instructions, and the bot is not working anymore (neither the old ones nor the new ones).

After submitting the credentials in `https://dev.botframework.com/`to add the Slack channel, everything appears to be ok, but in Slack the bot is always off-line, and the messages don't get botframework neither the messaging endpoint after that.

The only message I get in my messaging endpoint is:

```
{ type: 'installationUpdate',
        action: 'add',
        sourceEvent: 
         { SlackMessage: 
            { type: 'bot_added',
```

After adding the bot, but nothing after that. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some hours not working, the messages started to come again (it was a Microsoft or Slack problem)

Comment: @EricDahlvang I cannot accept it until 48 hours after making the question (tomorrow I will accept)